# How to programmatically hide windows associated with Desktop and Unity launcher and panel?

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, mono, c#

I'm developing WindowsForms Kiosk application using Mono 4.4.0, and I want no desktop related things being displayed when my application is launched. I.e. I want fully black, non clickable screen being seen when I hide one of my application forms and show another. Application is need to run under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64.

I was able to move Desktop and Unity launcher windows far away from 0,0 screen point using `wmctrl`. I.e. by executing following command for each window that I need to hide: `wmctrl -i -r 0x0300000a -e 0,2000,2000,0,0`. In this example `0x0300000a` is Desktop window ID, I got it from `wmctrl -l` command output. But although windows are moved they aren't exactly hidden. They became non clickable and aren't rerendered but still visible at their initial position.

A also tried to close Desktop window using following command: `wmctrl -i -c 0x0300000a`. But after Desktop window is closed logout is happening. Resize command in `wmctrl` take no effect on Desktop and Unity windows. `xdotool` didn't work for me either. I tried `windowminimize` and `windowunmap` commands with no result.

I know that on Windows you can find Desktop window using `FindWindow` user32.dll call and signal this window to hide.

Is there some way to do so in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: consider using different desktop environment, such as openbox

Comment: Looks like openbox is exactly what I need. Not only is solves desktop problem but it also let me add and remove key and mouse bindings via single xml file. Very nice! Consider posting it as an answer, so I can accept it.